# Msg 1949 and Msg 8668, when I create index view

Tags: sql-server

I want to create the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW vPRODUCT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT 
        PROD_ID AS PRODUCT_ID,
        YEAR(TIME_ID) AS YEAR,
        MONTH(TIME_ID) AS MONTH,
        DATEPART(WEEK, TIME_ID) AS WEEK,
        SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD,
        SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY_SOLD,
        ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD)/SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD),2) AS AVERAGE_SALE_PRICE,
        COUNT_BIG(*) AS COUNT
    FROM 
        dbo.SALES
    GROUP BY 
        PROD_ID, YEAR(TIME_ID), MONTH(TIME_ID), DATEPART(WEEK, TIME_ID);
```

Then create the index view:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V
    ON vPRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID, YEAR, MONTH);
```

This returns the message:

> Msg 1949, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Cannot create index on view 'dbo.vPRODUCT'. The function 'datepart' yields nondeterministic results. Use a deterministic system function, or modify the user-defined function to return deterministic results.

So, I try to create the following view (without WEEK):

```
CREATE VIEW vPRODUCT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT      
        PROD_ID AS PRODUCT_ID,
        YEAR(TIME_ID) AS YEAR,
        MONTH(TIME_ID) AS MONTH,
        SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD,
        SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD) AS TOTAL_QUANTITY_SOLD,
        ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD)/SUM(QUANTITY_SOLD),2) AS AVERAGE_SALE_PRICE,
        COUNT_BIG(*) AS COUNT
    FROM 
        dbo.SALES
    GROUP BY 
        PROD_ID, YEAR(TIME_ID), MONTH(TIME_ID);
```

Then create the index view:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V
    ON vPRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID, YEAR, MONTH);
```

And then I get this message:

> Msg 8668, Level 16, State 0, Line 14
>   Cannot create the clustered index 'IDX_V' on view 'dbo.vPRODUCT' because the select list of the view contains an expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column. Consider removing expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column from select list.

Is there anybody could point out what is wrong with the query?

Comment: Just make nested views so that you can maintain the materialized portion without having to perform expressions against the aggregated columns. Yes, that means some of those calculations won't be persisted, but that's not the end game of an indexed view anyway (it's the initial aggregation). Here's an equivalent example using AdventureWorks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2VJj.png

Comment: Thank you! Got it